# Burn image on image - Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, function

I know it's possible to put a text on an image, but does it work with an image. Can you help me or have you a site, where I get more informations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can composite images by using a `blendMode`.  There are several ways to go about this.  Here are two to get you started with the topic.

- The [Quartz 2D Programming Guide will help](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html) with a CoreGraphics approach.
- The [Core Image Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html) covers using CIFilters to blend images.